# Plug a DSolve solution into a funtion of it and its derivarives

Tags: differential-equations

Let us consider the case

```
sol=DSolve[{y'[x]+y[x]==0, y[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The solution is simple

```
{{y[x]->e^-x}}
```

Let us invent a function,

```
f=y'[x]+y[x]
```

When I write

```
f/.sol
```

I get

```
{e^-x + y'[x]}
```

What is the correct way to replace a solution into a function of it and its derivates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `y` instead of `y[x]` as the second argument of [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve):

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[x]+y[x]==0, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]

y'[x]+y[x] /. sol
```

> {{y -> Function[{x}, E^-x]}}
>
> {0}

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives don't replace as you would expect.  This works, however:

```
f = y'[x] + y[x]

f /. {y -> (E^(-#1) & )}
(*0*)
```